What is the difference between these two Capacitor types?
I'm designing a circuit which uses a Polypropylene Capacitor as a current limiter and a rectifier, zener regulator and smoothing chemical capacitor, however there are two types of Polypropylene Capacitors and I can't find the difference between them for this project but these are there pictures:


The yellow one isn't safety x2 rated capacitor, it is rated as Polypropylene Capacitor.
Update:
The schematic:

L is Live, N is Neutral (220 VAC)

Please post a schematic.. Most of your mentioned applications make no sense in the context of capacitors (IMO)

Although it's very self explanatory, this project is a private project however I will upload the needed part of it

If you aren't aware of it, it's safest to use a wall wart-type power supply which has an output galvanically isolated from the mains. And possibly cheaper, especially if you already have one that you can repurpose.

@AndrewMorton It is not possible unfortunately however it will be fully covered with plastic

Does this answer your question? What is an "XY" rated safety capacitor, exactly?
In your diagram there are two different applications of capacitors, the dropping capacitor, C0, needs to be X rated and the filter capacitor, C4, Y rated as they are both connected (directly or indirectly) to the mains. There are a couple of useful articles that explain further here and here.
I can see neither X nor Y rating markings in your images, so, unless there is any other information, neither is suitable for your application.

Why does C4 must be Y rated? In any normal SMPS where you rectify the mains directly to a bulk reservoir, it's typically a basic electrolytic, not a Y cap.

@Justme You could be right. It depends on the purpose of C4 to some extent. It could be considered as a filter capacitor to earth separated only by the rectifier diodes from mains and, as the X-rated capacitor is supposed to fail short, it should fail open (Y-rated). On the other hand it could be considered as a part of the reservoir capacitor dealing with the higher frequencies of the load, in which case it doesn't need to be Y-rated. If it were on the mains side of the rectifier, between line and earth, then it must be y-rated.

@PeterJennings But normally what is the real difference between those two capacitors stated in the photos above?

It can't be a capacitor to earth. It would trip a GFCI/RCBO immediately as all return current would flow in Earth wire instead of neutral.

@AndrewMorton Oops! I've fixed it now.

@HazardousVoltage There's no way of telling without reference to the data sheets. They could be anything.
